# As a client, what port am I supposed to connect to when running a MongoDB server that is connected to a NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, client-server

I have two ports running on my local network for a server: 27017 which is the port for the MongoDB, and 3000 which is the port for my nodejs app. I then connect the two using mongoose connect while listening on port 3000.

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')

app.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('listening on port 3000')
})
```

Previously I was trying to connect to the server via a web browser using http://(server ip):27017 but my GET which was written in my NodeJS app would never get called.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('hello world')
})
```

I switched the port to 3000, http://(server ip):3000 and finally I got a response from my GET.

So is this how clients should be connecting to their servers? Through their nodejs app and not to the database? Should clients also connect to the nodejs app when using TLS with HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser client should connect to your web server, not to the database so in
your example above, that would be on port 3000.

> So is this how clients should be connecting to their servers? Through their nodejs app and not to the database?

Yes.  The database is there for your server to use, not for the client to use directly.  Any client interaction with the database happens indirectly through your server.

> Should clients also connect to the nodejs app when using TLS with HTTP?

If the server is running locally only using localhost to access it, then there is likely no need for https.

It is generally recommended to run **public** servers on https these days.  That would mean that you would get a certificate from a certificate authority like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and use `https.createServer()` with the https credentials option in a general scheme like this example from the Let's Encrypt website:

```
// Dependencies
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello there !');
});

// Starting https server
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

Note, you would usually run an https server on port 443.  Then, you would connect to this server using the `https` protocol, not `http`.  You would not need to specify the port in the browser URL if you were using 443 (the default port number for https), but would need to specify the port if not using port 443.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer about "Should clients also connect to the nodejs app when using TLS with HTTP?", what I meant was: Should clients also connect to the nodejs app, instead of the database, when clients are attempting to connect using TLS with HTTP (https)?

Comment: @pgs1 - I'm still not sure what you're asking about TLS.  As best I know, there is no TLS with HTTP.  Somewhat by definition, TLS using the http protocol is HTTPS.  It's an HTTPS server where TLS is implemented for the client to connect to.  Now most of this is probably just semantics because the HTTP protocol + TLS is HTTPS.  In a browser, the way you tell the browser to use TLS is by starting your URL with `https://` (to specify the https protocol).

Comment: yes i meant HTTPS, I was confused since I just started learning about it. I also looked into the certificates that you were talking about and I think I was able to create an https connection between a server and a client by using the instructions [here](https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2)  to generate the appropriate certs and keys. Thanks for the help!